# Placeholder Mixin SCSS/CSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a mixin for placeholders in sass.

This is the mixin I've created.

```
@mixin placeholder ($css) {
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {$css}
  :-moz-placeholder           {$css}
  ::-moz-placeholder          {$css}
  :-ms-input-placeholder      {$css}  
}
```

This is how I'd like to include the mixin:

```
@include placeholder(font-style:italic; color: white; font-weight:100;);
```

Obviously this isn't going to work because of all the colons and semi-colons that's being passed through to the mixin, but... I'd really like to just input static css and pass it through exactly like the above function.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You're looking for the `@content` directive:

```
@mixin placeholder {
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {@content}
  :-moz-placeholder           {@content}
  ::-moz-placeholder          {@content}
  :-ms-input-placeholder      {@content}  
}

@include placeholder {
    font-style:italic;
    color: white;
    font-weight:100;
}
```

SASS Reference has more information, which can be found here:
http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content

---

As of Sass 3.4, this mixin can be written like so to work both nested and unnested:

```
@mixin optional-at-root($sel) {
  @at-root #{if(not &, $sel, selector-append(&, $sel))} {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin placeholder {
  @include optional-at-root('::-webkit-input-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }

  @include optional-at-root(':-moz-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }

  @include optional-at-root('::-moz-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }

  @include optional-at-root(':-ms-input-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
.foo {
  @include placeholder {
    color: green;
  }
}

@include placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Output:

```
.foo::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
.foo:-moz-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
.foo::-moz-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
.foo:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was reverted, but the answer is incorrect. You need '@' at the beginning of each of the individual vendor prefixes. Take a look at an answer further down by Dave Hein, or better yet - try to run this code, and you'll see it wont work.

Comment: @RickM It was reverted because the modifications you made don't compile (error:  Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'.).  This creates the exact output the OP is looking for, the answer you claim is "correct" does not.

Comment: Interesting...are you compiling via cli? Looks like there must be a versioning conflict as the exact opposite happens for me, and judging by other replies, a few others too.

Comment: Yes, CLI:  Sass 3.3.0.rc.3 via Compass.  Double checked with [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/) and [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).  The `&` is necessary if you want to be able to get a selector like `input::-webkit-input-placeholder` with the mixin, but it will prevent you from using it at the root level.  http://sassmeister.com/gist/9469073.  Now if you're using LibSass, that's a different story.

Comment: This is not going to work if nested. Dave's answer below is the way to go.

Comment: This answer does not work answer anymore. The gist by @cimmanon is not same as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 176):

I found the approach given by [cimmanon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon) and [Kurt Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527472/kurt-mueller) almost worked, but that I needed a parent reference (i.e., I need to add the '&' prefix to each vendor prefix); like this:

```
@mixin placeholder {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {@content}
    &:-moz-placeholder           {@content}
    &::-moz-placeholder          {@content}
    &:-ms-input-placeholder      {@content}  
}
```

I use the mixin like this:

```
input {
    @include placeholder {
        font-family: $base-font-family;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

With the parent reference in place, then correct css gets generated, e.g.:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", Lucidabright, "Lucida Serif", Lucida, "DejaVu Serif", "Liberation Serif", Georgia, serif;
    color: red;
}
```

Without the parent reference (&), then a space is inserted before the vendor prefix and the CSS processor ignores the declaration; that looks like this:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", Lucidabright, "Lucida Serif", Lucida, "DejaVu Serif", "Liberation Serif", Georgia, serif;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me hours of trial and error in order to make the accepted answer/solution work...

Comment: It is worth noting that that your selectors are now slightly overqualified (unless you genuinely don't want it to work on input or select elements).  Adding the parent selector prevents you from using the mixin without nesting (which was what the OP was looking for).

Comment: The `&` is totally necessary. Edited the popular answer to reflect this.

Comment: +1. Some browsers support the official `::placeholder` property now, so I'd recommend adding this at the top: `&::placeholder               {@content}`

Answer (score 11):

This is for shorthand syntax

```
=placeholder
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder
    @content
  &:-moz-placeholder
    @content
  &::-moz-placeholder
    @content
  &:-ms-input-placeholder
    @content
```

use it like

```
input
  +placeholder
    color: red
```

Comment: I honestly think this is harder to read and also not as neat as the regular syntax

Comment: I tried to put it as a comment, but is too large. I rather use this syntax, and couldn't make the chosen answer work too easily . I thought it could be useful for someone else.

Comment: this one is the best, easy to understand and implement.

Answer (score 3):

Why not something like this?

It uses a combination of lists, iteration, and interpolation.

```
@mixin placeholder ($rules) {

  @each $rule in $rules {
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder,
    :-moz-placeholder,
    ::-moz-placeholder,
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      #{nth($rule, 1)}: #{nth($rule, 2)};
    }  
  }
}

$rules: (('border', '1px solid red'),
         ('color', 'green'));

@include placeholder( $rules );
```

Comment: It's just a bit to complicated, I was looking for the content directive but thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid 'Unclosed block: CssSyntaxError' errors being thrown from sass compilers add a ';' to the end of @content.

```
@mixin placeholder {
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder { @content;}
   :-moz-placeholder           { @content;}
   ::-moz-placeholder          { @content;}
   :-ms-input-placeholder      { @content;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use exactly the same sass mixin placeholder as NoDirection wrote. I find it in sass mixins collection [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-mixins-collection) and I'm very satisfied with it. There's [a text](https://kolosek.com/sass-mixins/) that explains a mixins option more.