# Mixin for Group Pseudo Classes with SASS

Tags: css, sass

Ideally I want to create a mixin to style all the placeholder pseudo classes. I'm not sure if this is even possible. Here's what I have:

```
@mixin placeholder($color) {
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: $color;
  }
  :-moz-placeholder {
    color: $color;
  }
  ::-moz-placeholder {
    color: $color;
  }
  :-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

Which ideally would be used like this:

```
input {
    &@placeholder(red);
}
```

And would result in this CSS:

```
  input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: red;
  }
  input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
  }
```

Comment: why not use @content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placeholder Mixin SCSS/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181849/placeholder-mixin-scss-css)

Comment: @agconti What is `@content`? cimmanon, it's not quite the same because I don't want to apply it site wide.

Comment: There's more than one answer there, try reading the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parent selector `&` before each selector like this:

```
@mixin placeholder($color) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        color: $color;
    }
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        color: $color;
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        color: $color;
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: $color;
    }
}
```

and then include it in your code:

```
input {
    @include placeholder(red);
}
```