# ::-webkit-input-placeholder does not work

Tags: html, css, sass, webkit, placeholder

i'm writing a mobile web sites and i'm styling it with sass.

I would like to change the placeholder color of textinput, but i'm not able to do this.

This is the mixin for the placeholder

```
@mixin placeholder($color) {
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: $color}
  :-moz-placeholder           {color: $color}
  ::-moz-placeholder          {color: $color}
  :-ms-input-placeholder      {color: $color}
}
```

And then i use it included into a class

```
.input-class {
    @include placeholder(#FFFFFF);
}
```

Finally set the class to the input

```
<input class="input-class" ...>
```

But nothing happens. In addition my IDE set an error on the mixins lines saying me: "Unknown pseudo selector -webkit-input-placeholder" and chrome seems to not recognize that tag.

How can I change the color of placeholder? No matter if the response is in sass or css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17181946/1652962

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't use it single, only with selector:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #9B9B9B;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #9B9B9B;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #9B9B9B;
}
```

**Mixin:**

```
@mixin placeholder($selector, $color) {
  #{$selector}::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: $color}
  #{$selector}::-moz-placeholder          {color: $color}
  #{$selector}:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: $color}
}
```

**Usage**:

```
@include placeholder('.input-class', #FFFFFF);
```

[**Live example**](http://codepen.io/frontenddeveloping/full/EaWQbr)

**P.S.** Do not use them all together (this selector is broken and css parser will always fails):

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,//Not WebKit will fails here
input:-ms-input-placeholder,//Not IE will fails here
input::-moz-placeholder {//Not Firefox will fails here
    color: #9B9B9B;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i have to make an application that works on all browsers...if i cannot use them togheter, how could i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your and my mixins are right. Its work fine. My note is about creation of common selector of all placeholders selectors.

Comment: Sorry another time but it still not works :(

Comment: All works, example http://codepen.io/frontenddeveloping/full/EaWQbr

Comment: Maybe is a frameworek issue...

Comment: +1 for P.S. I've spent an hour pulling my hair out because of this. BTW, Firefox swallows that just fine, but Chrome refuses.

Comment: Your last part fixes my issue (cannot use them all together). Thank you