# Unable to convert placeholder value to bold in SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am naive to SCSS. I'm planning to convert the 'data-placeholder' following code in html to bold in SCSS:

```
 <optic-select-input id="placeholder"data-placeholder="Choose or type  
  subject..."  title = "Type your subject">
```

Here is my effort in SCSS:

```
 optic-select-input {
     data-placeholder {
         font-weight: bold;
     }
 }
```

However, this is not showing any impact. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `data-placeholder` isn't a standar attribute, is a generic `data-*`  attribute, it does nothing by itself. I suppose you have a JavaScript which read the value of `data-placeholder` and display it. Can you show us a working example?

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

more info on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

**Update**

[Placeholder Mixin SCSS/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181849/placeholder-mixin-scss-css)

Comment: This is css , I want SCSS

Comment: _"This is css , I want SCSS"_ Of course, the selectors in CSS, in SCSS or in any prepocessor are the same.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins

```
@import 'compass-mixins/lib/compass';

.optic-select-input{
  @include input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
```